# Where/If to release properties in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access, nszombie

EDIT: Ok, so i figured out how to remedy my original problem, but i'm not sure if this is the best way.

My new question is, say I have a subclass of UITableViewCell with the following property declaration in the header:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *levelLabel;
```

This is connected in IB. Is it ok to not release this in dealloc, and not release it at all?  This is the only way I can figure out to get it to work, without giving me an exc_bad_access error. Before, it called dealloc when the tableviewcell went off the screen but then it still needed it. where do i release stuff, or does it take care of that for me?

Original Title: Memory leak in UITableView and exc_bad_access
Ok, I am confused. I was following along with this tutorial online making custom UITableViewCells. I made one, and i did everything like the tutorial told me. My UITableViewCell subclass contains 3 UILabels and 3 UIButtons, and has all of them defined as properties and connected in IB. I need them to be available to the class because i need to know when the buttons are pressed and be able to change the text. When I run the app, i start scrolling and after a few seconds it crashes, with exc_bad_access in main (no output in the console). But when I run the app in instruments with NSZombieEnabled, it does not crash at all, and runs just fine. However, since instruments shows you the allocations, i can see them going up very quickly, especially as I scroll. I dont know if this is all allocations, or if these are being released, but still it seems too fast.

Here is PointCoordinatesCell.h (my custom cell):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PointCoordinatesCell : UITableViewCell


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *levelLabelLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *levelLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *levelDescriptionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *beginningButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *developingButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *secureButton;

@end
```

PointCoordinatesCell.m:

```
#import "PointCoordinatesCell.h"

@implementation PointCoordinatesCell
@synthesize levelLabel, levelLabelLabel, levelDescriptionLabel, beginningButton, developingButton, secureButton;

- (void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [levelLabel release];
    [levelLabelLabel release];
    [levelDescriptionLabel release];
    [beginningButton release];
    [developingButton release];
    [secureButton release];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

RootViewController.h has nothing in it other than a class declaration and standard imports. No variables or methods defined. It subclasses UITableViewController.

RootViewController.m:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "StatesAppDelegate.h"
#import "PointCoordinatesCell.h"

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}

#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 50;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    return 293;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PointCoordinatesCell";

    PointCoordinatesCell *cell = (PointCoordinatesCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PointCoordinatesCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (PointCoordinatesCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //cell.capitalLabel.text = [capitals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.stateLabel.text = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    // AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];
    // [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController];
    // [anotherViewController release];
}



- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are doing some complicated casting in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. I do not think this is necessary. It does not seem logical to me to check for an object of class `UITableViewCell` and then cast it into a custom cell. The cell in your nib should already be a custom cell.

In the Apple sample the loading of the cell is much more straight forward. You link your custom cell to an `IBOutlet` in your view controller and then do this:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = customTableViewCell;
    self.customTableViewCell = nil;
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not okay to not release the label. You declared the property with 'retain'-specifier. That means you will have to release it at least in dealloc (A safe way to do that is: `self. levelLabel = nil;`).

As you've noticed the memory consumption will raise during scrolling if you don't release the objects (memory leaks!).

You'll have to tell where the exc_bad_access error occurs so that we can help you ...